# android:showAsAction in XML killing AAPT.EXE

Tags: android, xml, menu

I am attempting to add a second menu to support the android:showAsAction element for 3.0 android and above, but every time I add the item to my menu.xml AAPT.EXE keeps crashing.

Doesn't matter what I do, aapt.exe crashes every time I add this to the menu.xml.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the menu XML, and ideally any error messages that come from **`aapt`**, it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: There is nothing special about the menu.xml just putting custom:showAsAction="never" into any ITEM of the xml causes the problem.

Problem signature from AAPT crash, for what its worth:

Comment: Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: aapt.exe
  Application Version: 0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp: 52684cb5
  Fault Module Name: aapt.exe
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp: 52684cb5
  Exception Code: c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0003cf2a
  OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID: 1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Comment: Or android:showAsAction="never"  I tried using custom from another question on here, but it proved no different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, had to modify my targetSDK setting to a version higher than the showAsAction tag existed.

Comment: This doesn't resolve the crash. I have set that latest API19 as target and aapt still crashes. It always crashes if you make mistake in "showAsAction". That's a bug in aapt.

Comment: there was no mistake in the showAsAction or its settings (no typos etc) All I did was change to a later targetSDK that was newer than the addition of the setting.  I am sure that if you enter showAsAction wrong the app may crash, but that was not what was causing it in my case.